# DB2 table change tracking

Tags: db2, db2-400

I would like to track IBM DB2 table data changes (Inserts, updates, deletes), and insert changes into an other table.

What would be the easiest solution ? It is a IBM DB2 for iSeries on AS400.

For example, could it be possible to add triggers to track these changes in a specific table I will poll ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have journaling enabled and capturing both before and after images? If yes, you can get all the information related to data changes from journals.

Comment: I don't know, I only have access to a sql console using the IBM DB2 app. Can I check it using SQL ? Or where do I have to search the information ?

Comment: You can view journal information using table function  QSYS2.Display_Journal. See following link for more details. 


https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home/wiki/IBM+i+Technology+Updates/page/DISPLAY_JOURNAL+(easier+searches+of+Audit+Journal)

Answer (score 0):

I think a trigger would work best for you. Please note, the system will need to devote resources to tracking these so let your system operator know!.

Here is what I would do:

1. Create a copy of the file you want to track changes on:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE LIB.TABLEHST AS (SELECT * FROM LIB.TABLE) WITH NO DATA;
   ```
2. Add columns for the operation and datetime:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE LIB.TABLEHST
   ADD COLUMN OPERATION CHAR(10),
   ADD COLUMN DATEMODIFIED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
   ```
3. Create your trigger to track inserts:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER LIB.TABLEINS
   AFTER INSERT ON LIB.TABLE
   REFERENCING NEW AS M
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN ATOMIC
   INSERT INTO LIB.TABLEHST (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, OPERATION, DATEMODIFIED)
   VALUES (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, 'INSERT', CURRENT TIMESTAMP);
   END;
   ```
4. Create your trigger to track updates:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER LIB.TABLEUPD
   AFTER UPDATE ON LIB.TABLE
   REFERENCING NEW AS M
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN ATOMIC
   INSERT INTO LIB.TABLEHST (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, OPERATION, DATEMODIFIED)
   VALUES (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, 'UPDATE', CURRENT TIMESTAMP);
   END;
   ```
5. Create your trigger to track deletes:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER LIB.TABLEDEL
   AFTER DELETE ON LIB.TABLE
   REFERENCING NEW AS M
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN ATOMIC
   INSERT INTO LIB.TABLEHST (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, OPERATION, DATEMODIFIED)
   VALUES (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, 'DELETE', CURRENT TIMESTAMP);
   END;
   ```
6. Edit: Test and make sure things are working correctly by doing an insert, update, and delete!

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The trigger for delete needs to reference OLD not NEW.

```
CREATE TRIGGER LIB.TABLEDEL
AFTER DELETE ON LIB.TABLE
REFERENCING **OLD** AS M
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO LIB.TABLEHST (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, OPERATION, DATEMODIFIED)
VALUES (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, 'DELETE', CURRENT TIMESTAMP);
END;
```